# Compile error for AI Thinker ESP32-CAM card

Tags: c, esp32, microprocessors

Hello I am a beginner of C language for microprocessors. I want to copy a `.bmp` file using `copyimage()` function .This error occurs when compile button is pushed:

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "FS.h"                // SD Card ESP32
#include "SD_MMC.h"            // SD Card ESP32
#include "soc/soc.h"           // Disable brownour problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  // Disable brownour problems
#include "driver/rtc_io.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>            // read and write from flash memory
#include <SPI.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// define the number of bytes you want to access
#define EEPROM_SIZE 1
// Pin definition for CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

int pictureNumber = 0;
int CopyNumber = 0;

void imgWriter(const char *imgName,
               unsigned char *buf,
               int len,
               int width,
               int height)// WRITE A FILE
               {
                  fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC;
                  Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n",imgName);
                  Serial.printf("%d\n",len);
                  Serial.printf("%d\n",width);
                  Serial.printf("%d\n",height);
                  File fo =fs.open(imgName,FILE_WRITE);
                  if(!fo){
                    Serial.println("Failed to open file in writing mode");
                  }
                  else {
                    fo.write(buf,len);    // payload (image), payload length
                    Serial.printf("Saved file to path: %s\n" , imgName);
                    EEPROM.write(0, pictureNumber);
                    EEPROM.commit();
                  }
                  fo.close();
                  }
void copyImage(const char *imgName,
               int width,
               int height,
               const char *copyimage)     // COPY A FILE
              {
                 fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC;     // Allows access to SD card
                 File fo =fs.open(imgName,FILE_READ);
                 File fy =fs.open(copyimage,FILE_WRITE);
                 if(!fo){
                    Serial.printf("Unable to open file for reading");
                 }
                 unsigned char header[54];
                 unsigned char colorTable[1024];
                 
                 for(int i =0 ; i<54 ; i++){
                      header[i]= getc(fo);   // ERROR IS HERE
                 }
                 
                 int width1 = * ( int * )&header[18];   //Width information of the image
                 int height1 = * ( int * ) &header[22];
                 int bitDepth = * ( int * ) &header[28];
                 
                 if(bitDepth <= 8 ){
                      fo.read(colorTable,1024);
                 }
                 
                 fy.write(header,54);
                 unsigned char buf[(height1*width1)];
                 fo.read(buf,(height1 * width1));
                 
                 if(bitDepth <= 8){
                      fy.write(colorTable,1024);
                 }

                 fy.write(buf,(height1*width1));
                 fy.close();
                 fo.close();
                 Serial.printf("SUCCESS");
                 EEPROM.commit();
              }
void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  //Serial.println();
  
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 
  
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA; // FRAMESIZE_ + QVGA|CIF|VGA|SVGA|XGA|SXGA|UXGA
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
  
  // Init Camera
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
  
  //Serial.println("Starting SD Card");
  if(!SD_MMC.begin()){
    Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  
  uint8_t cardType = SD_MMC.cardType();
  if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
    Serial.println("No SD Card attached");
    return;
  }
    
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  
  // Take Picture with Camera
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }               
  // initialize EEPROM with predefined size
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  pictureNumber = EEPROM.read(0) + 1;
  CopyNumber = EEPROM.read(0) + 1;

  // Path where new picture will be saved in SD Card
  String path = "/picture" + String(pictureNumber) +".bmp";   // Dosyanın ismi
  String copy_path = "/Copy" + String(CopyNumber) +".bmp";

  imgWriter(path.c_str(),fb->buf,fb->len,fb->width,fb->height); // WRITE FUNCION CALL
  copyImage(path.c_str(),fb->width,fb->height,copy_path.c_str()); // Copy
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
  // Turns off the ESP32-CAM white on-board LED (flash) connected to GPIO 4
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  rtc_gpio_hold_en(GPIO_NUM_4);
  
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Going to sleep now");
  delay(2000);
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
  Serial.println("This will never be printed");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Error is : cannot convert 'fs::File' to 'FILE* {aka __sFILE*}' for argument '1' to 'int getc(FILE*)'

Comment: Surely there's a better error message than that.

Comment: `* ( int * ) & header[18]` is unlikely to work. In addition to endian issues, you also have alignment problems. It's worth noting that `&x` is "address of `x`" while `& x` (with a space) is presumed to mean "logical AND `x`" which is not what you mean. The compiler doesn't care, but spacing your operations out like this is confusing.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the full and complete error output, copy-pasted as text. Also add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: I have editted my question, I have shared the full version of my code, thank you.

Comment: We can't "compile on our own computer" because we don't have the same build environment you do. You're going to have to find a better error message, or do some digging on your own to see what's causing it. Does a minimal program compile? If you're using version control, check this in, then start deleting as much as you can until it compiles, then work backwards to what caused the problem.

Comment: I think I have found the problem but I dont know how to solve. Problem is at  `for(int i =0 ; i<54 ; i++){header[i]= getc(fo);}` after I write this, compiler does not compile...

Comment: Why not just use `fo.read(...)` like you've done in other places?

Comment: [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) is inherited from C. It doesn't know anything about `File` objects. And there must be *somewhere* in your IDE where you can see the compiler telling you this.

Comment: I have editted my question again. I have found that when I include fstream library, it gives me different error now. I think I have to initialize  'fs (SD card handler) ' to other pointers but I dont know how can I do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the comments, your error is quite clear from the message and code:

You are trying to use a C library function `getc` with a ESP32 library object `File`.

That is impossible. `getc` can not work with this object, or any C++ object because it is a C function.

To read from the file object, you need to use its method `read` like this:

```
header[i] = fo.read();
```

You should read the library documentation for more information on how to use the `File` object, or see this tutorial on working with SD card:

https://diyi0t.com/sd-card-arduino-esp8266-esp32/